# Hide Android status bar on the homescreen

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to hide the status bar that is displayed on the homescreen of the device, when not in any applications.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking programatically how to do this?  LauncherPro provides a hide status bar option...

Comment: I use Home++ as my home/launcher and it can do this.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. There is always some activity running, to hide status bar you need to use a full screen app over the top (full screen app maybe be a homescreen)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android 1.x and 2.x, you can write your own home screen.

On Android 3.x, this is impossible.

In all versions, you cannot remove the status bar from another application.